# Ideavim writes letter "u" instead of adding a line when typing <cr> (hitting return button)

Tags: macos, android-studio, mapping, ideavim

In Android Studio 3.5.3 (using Ideavim 0.55) when in insert mode I hit return, it types the letter "u". How do I disable it?

Here is my .vimrc file: https://github.com/tomasbaran/My-Bash-Setup/blob/master/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: a typo in my .vimrc file: Had to remove the "u" that shouldn't be there.

[image: "u" shouldn't be there]